Why holes are not desirable in latent space of autoencoders?
It has been stated in several studies of autoencoders that a vanilla autoencoder (autoencoder without any regularizer) may suffer from holes in the latent space. The meaning of hole is described as discontinuous regions in the latent space of the autoencoders. I am not able to understand two things
I) discontinuous regions. I think it means that manifold obtained after mapping the data into latent space is not continuous.
II) Why they are not desirable?
For an example, see section 2 in
Mazumder, Alokendu, Tirthajit Baruah, Bhartendu Kumar, Rishab Sharma, Vishwajeet Pattanaik, and Punit Rathore. "Learning Low-Rank Latent Spaces with Simple Deterministic Autoencoder: Theoretical and Empirical Insights." In Proceedings of the IEEE/CVF Winter Conference on Applications of Computer Vision, pp. 2851-2860. 2024.

One possible reason why you might not want them is linear interpolation, meaning that you want to go from one sample to another while staying in distribution. If the distribution has "holes" (or is not convex, generally speaking), at some point in the linear combination of the two respective latent spaces, you risk going out of distribution.
